# How to run browsers concurrently/simultaneously with Selenium Grid to search a list of strings in parts (in Java)

Tags: java, concurrency, webdriver, selenium-grid

I want to be able to take a list of Strings, split the list into parts, and have each browser running search a part of the list (i.e. browser1 does 1/5, browser2 does 2/5...) in let's say Google (I happen to be using Firefox).

How would I go about doing this using Selenium Grid. I have it set-up, and I know how to register the hub and nodes to that hub, but if it helps your explanation or the solution involves a different kind of instantiation, then let me know. I think it would help other users reading this to just have that thrown in...

A step-by-step solution would satisfy me though. I just can not get Selenium to function the browsers concurrently, even with 2 nodes. Is it required that I use TestNG or Mable or something (I'm not familiar with these)? I wish to one day have this program developed into a Win32 application (in C++/C#), so it can't just run in a "test suite" if I can't encapsulate it later for distribution.

**EDIT:** 
Here's the framework of what I mean. Obviously it will not accomplish the task, as I am asking the question now. I don't know if this would require multiple drivers or even multiple copies of the same program running in memory, so I will comment appropriately in the code. This is in no way yet made to be concurrent-just the task I wish to make concurrent on the grid.

```
public void beginSearch(){

    ArrayList<String> searchTerms=new ArrayList<String>();
    //Pretend searchTerms is full of 100 Strings!

    //Create a new instance of the Firefox Driver
    capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

    //Let's say I have one WebDriver object for now 
    try{
        driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }catch (MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Go to Google
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    for(int i=0; i<searchTerms.size(); i++){

         /*I put the findElement() inside the loop due to experience with it
          *not being able to interact with the same element on a different page when
          *the URL changes. I think it's due to XPath use internally in the WebElement
          *class. Ignore this for now.
          */
         element=driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
         element.sendKeys(searchTerms.get(i));
         element.submit();
    }

    driver.quit;
}
/*Let's say for the hell of it this is all I wanted to do-how could I make it perform
 *this concurrently on the Grid!?
 */
```

Comment: Are you instantiating multiple instances of the web driver?  How are you concurrently executing the code on your Java machine?  Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: I have removed my original attempts. I have no current code to provide, because I'm not debugging a particular attempt.

At first I tried multithreading, but it wasn't thread-safe (even though there's thread guard for it which people said worked), so I got aboard with Grid2, but now there's people doing test "suites" with things like TestNG and using XMLs and blah. I just thought I could run 5 browsers concurrently with 5 instances of WebDriver but something's missing. I'd appreciate it if you could tell me what.

Like I said, I'd put code there but it's a code problem yet. I'll in the future.

Comment: *it's NOT a code problem yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting... so as far as I know making the connection to the WebDriver in code is no different than connecting directly to the WebDriver, in terms the actual code you use.  You can connect to an individual node in the same manner in which you connect to the grid.  The grid is simply responsible for determining which node to hand off the test to and queue requests when there aren't any available nodes.  You should be able to connect the Selenium Grid2 using a WebDriver on an individual thread without any problems, so long as you're not sharing references.  I think the general rule is one WebDriver per thread.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

You don't absolutely need something like TestNG.  TestNG contains a lot of nice functionality like ways of providing large data sets, advanced logging capabilities, test suites, etc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestNG

Here is an incredibly basic idea.  Each test is run on it's own thread with each instance of the WebDriver running on it's own thread. I've not tested this code.

```
public class Tests {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int threadCount = 0; threadCount<5; threadCount++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //Create a new instance of the Firefox Driver
                    capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

                    //Let's say I have one WebDriver object for now 
                    try{
                        driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
                    }catch (MalformedURLException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //Go to Google
                    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

                    //Quit Driver
                    driver.quit;
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You kind've just explained what WebDriver is in terms of the Grid and how the grid handles that. Though the inclusive in the answer I sought, I did know that. I would simply like an example of code that declares whatever necessary WebDrivers in whatever fashion on the Grid and runs CONCURRENT searches of a List on google, let's say {Red, Yellow, Blue, Green, Orange, Purple, Brown, Black, Pink}, where browser 1 does Red-Blue, 2 does Green-Purple, and 3 does Brown-Pink. The idea is it does not utilize a test suite, if possible.

And thanks for the links. I've seen them, but learned something new

Comment: I'll edit the question to contain the framework of what I mean. Should've done that to being with...

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend trying to manage your threads in this fashion, but trying this might reveal problems:

```
WebDriver driver = ThreadGuard.protect( 
      new RemoteWebDriver( "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub", capabilities) );
```

I use TestNG to manage my threads and so I don't need to worry much about this stuff.